# Dynamically created list needs links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, loops

I have successfully created a list from JSON response...

```
function loadList() {
   $.getJSON("http://www.JSONURLDATA/TEST", function (Cust) {
      var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo('#custList');
      for (var i = 0; i < Cust.Customers.length; i++) {
         ul.append($(document.createElement('li')).text('(' + Cust.Customers[i].Keycode + ') ' + Cust.Customers[i].Name));
         console.log(Cust.Customers[i].Name);
      }
   })
}
```

Is it possible to create the href part within this loop?

Comment: What do you want the generated HTML to look like? Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: what "href" part? show us the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. This is one way:

```
ul.append(
    $(document.createElement('li'))
        .text(
            $(document.createElement('a'))
                .attr('href', 'whatever_you_like')
                .html('(' + Cust.Customers[i].Keycode + ') ' + Cust.Customers[i].Name)
        )
);
```

This code is adding a link within the `li` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

You are already setting the dynamic element's contents like this:

```
(yourNewItem).text('(' + Cust.Customers[i].Keycode + ') ' + Cust.Customers[i].Name)
```

You can also set *any* attribute you want like so:

```
(yourNewItem).attr("attributeName", "value");
```

So in your case:

```
(yourNewItem).attr("href", "http://www.google.com");
```

And yes, you can paste that directly inline with the `.text()` call, these methods are perfectly chainable :)

**EDIT** It doesn't make sense for a `<li>` element. But the point is the same, you can set *any* (I think. Maybe a rare exception) attribute on *any* (again, I think) element using that method.

If I recall correctly, you can even invent your own attributes using that method. Not that I'm suggesting you do so; I only mean to explain how universal that method is :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ul.append($(document.createElement('li')).text('(' + Cust.Customers[i].Keycode + ') ' + Cust.Customers[i].Name));
```

Do

```
ul.append(
  $("<li></li>").append(
     $("<a></a>").attr("href","URL").text('(' + Cust.Customers[i].Keycode + ') ' + Cust.Customers[i].Name)
  )
);
```